# Escape-event not working with svelte store

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte writable store that defines the code for a modal popup.

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
let visible = false;

const openModal = () => {
    if(visible) return;
    visible = true;

    // Close modal on escape
    document.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape);
}

const closeModal = () => {
    if(!visible) return;
    visible = false;
}

const closeOnEscape = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if(e.key === 'Escape') closeModal();
    console.log(visible);
}


// Modal store
const ModalStore = () => {
    const { subscribe, set } = writable(visible);

    return {
        subscribe,
        openModal: () => {
            openModal();
            set(visible);
        },

        closeModal: () => {
            closeModal();
            set(visible);
        },
        
        unsubscribe: () => {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape);
        }
    }
}

export default ModalStore();
```

I am tracking the ***visible*** value using $ModalStore to open and close the popup.

Everything works except the escape key. I tried ***console.log(visible)*** on the closeOnEscape function and it returns "false" as intended. But the div is not closing. The div is as follows

```
{#if $ModalStore}
   <div>Modal Popup</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your close logic is disconnected from the store. It calls the functions that set `visible` but the store is unaffected. You should simply *only use a store* instead of two separate variables that are supposed to be the same.

Also: `unsubscribe` is not part of the store contract. By having a separate function, which will **not** be called automatically, you make it easier for leaks to occur.

Stores are unsubscribed from by invoking the function returned by `subscribe`. If you want special unsubscribe logic, you should wrap `subscribe` and return a function that calls the regular unsubscribe function and whatever custom logic you have.

Adding an event listener on `open` but not removing it on `close` is also bound to cause issues.

---

Example:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { onMount } from "svelte";

export function createModalStore() {
    const visible = writable(false);

    onMount(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape);

        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape);
    });
    
    function closeOnEscape(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Escape')
            visible.set(false);
    }

    return {
        subscribe: visible.subscribe,
        openModal: () => visible.set(true),
        closeModal: () => visible.set(false),
    }
}
```

Usage

```html
<script>
    import { createModalStore } from './modal';
    
    const modal = createModalStore();
</script>

<button on:click={() => modal.openModal()}>
    Open
</button>

{#if $modal}
    Modal
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/100ec3fc0419406c8883d6c1c1437e1b?version=3.52.0)

The event listener is only once and ensured to be cleaned up together with the component that uses the store via the destroy function returned from `onMount`.

`openModal`/`closeModal` are fairly redundant and could also be replaced by just exporting a `set` function so it could be closed via `$modal = false`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Could you please do some edit in the code so that I can understand better.

Comment: Added an example.